Adapting Chrome Extension Code from Manifest V2 to V3: Tackling requestBody Capture
So, I'm thinking of making an extension that changes the response depending on some conditions. Like, if request hit a URL at /graphql, using POST, and the request body has a certain key-value pair; then modify the response.
const newResponse = {...};

const callback = (details) => {
  if (details.method !== 'POST') return { cancel: false };
  if (details.requestBody.raw.length < 1) return { cancel: false };

  const bodyRaw = details.requestBody.raw[0];
  const bodyBytes = bodyRaw.bytes;
  const bodyUint8Array = new Uint8Array(bodyBytes);
  const bodyString = new TextDecoder().decode(bodyUint8Array);
  const body = JSON.parse(bodyString);

  if (body.key !== 'value') return { cancel: false };

  return {
    redirectUrl: "data:application/json;charset=utf-8," +
      encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(newResponse))
  };
};

const filter = {
  types: [ 'xmlhttprequest' ],
  urls: [ 'http://*/graphql' ]
};

const opt_extraInfoSpec = [
  'blocking',
  'requestBody'
];

chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  callback, filter, opt_extraInfoSpec
);

I know the code is only good for Manifest V2 or older, and webRequestBlocking is deprecated in Manifest V3.
But how do I grab requestBody using declarativeNetRequest or some other trick to get this code migrating smoothly in Manifest V3?

declarativeNetRequest can't do it. You can suggest the feature in https://crbug.com or WECG. Workarounds: 1) install the extension via policies so it's able to use webRequestBlocking, 2) use chrome.debugger API, 3) inject a content script in the MAIN world that overrides fetch and XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send, but this won't work inside workers.
